# Catch tap in React Native ScrollView while keyboard is up

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to catch taps on a React Native ScrollView while the keyboard is up? Or any React Native container for that matter?

I see the ScrollView property [keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) and [keyboardDismissMode](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboarddismissmode) that allows some control of how taps are handled while the keyboard is up. But no combination seems to allow taps to be handled normally.

The use case is a search field where the search is updated on keypress. When the entry appears in the list below the input, and the user taps it, I want the app to react to that tap. Right now it just dismissed the keyboard and the user has to tap again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like I answered my own question; setting [keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) to `'always'` or `'handled'` on a ScrollView will pass taps to the components in that ScrollView even when the keyboard is up.

Comment: And if not in a ScrollView try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808294/react-native-ha‌​ve-to-double-click-f‌​or-onpress-to-work

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the  keyboardShouldPersistTaps to 'always' on your list too.

Check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42815548/2887460