# React Native have to double click for onPress to work

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm using React Native with the Native Base library. I need an onPress event to fire on Native Base' ListItem (equivalent to TouchableOpacity) when the keyboard is open.

I now have to click once to close the keyboard and then I can press the ListItem.

Content tag below is equivalent to ScrollableView:

```
<Content keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'>
  <List>
    <ListItem style={styles.inspectionsItemDivider} itemDivider>
      <TextInput
        autoFocus={true}
        ref={(input) => { this.titleSearch = input }}
        placeholder='Start typing...'
        multiline={true}
        onChangeText={this.setSearchText.bind(this)}
        value={this.getSearchValue()}/>
    </ListItem>
    <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.recentText}>Recommended Descriptions</Text>
      <List dataArray={this.state.searchedDescriptions} 
        renderRow={(description) =>
        <ListItem button onPress={() => this.setInformationDescription(description)}>
          <Text>{description}</Text>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </View>
  </List>
</Content>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I actually just figured this out. I added the keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' prop to my List, in addition to the Content tag:

```html
<Content keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'>
  <List>
    <ListItem style={styles.inspectionsItemDivider} itemDivider>
      <TextInput
        autoFocus={true}
        ref={(input) => { this.titleSearch = input }}
        placeholder='Start typing...'
        multiline={true}
        onChangeText={this.setSearchText.bind(this)}
        value={this.getSearchValue()}/>
    </ListItem>
    <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.recentText}>Recommended Descriptions</Text>
      <List keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always' dataArray={this.state.searchedDescriptions} 
        renderRow={(description) =>
        <ListItem button onPress={() => this.setInformationDescription(description)}>
          <Text>{description}</Text>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    </View>
  </List>
</Content>
```

Answer (score 6):

For new googlers, in my case, I had a flatlist with an onPress property, and a searchBar. I wanted to press the row even when the keyboard is up, and I could do it only by double tap.Finally the problem was tackled by using "keyboardShouldPersistTaps" of the flatlist:

```
Hide_Soft_Keyboard=()=>{
      Keyboard.dismiss();
    }

....

                <List>
                      <FlatList
                        keyboardShouldPersistTaps = "always"
                        ...
                        renderItem={({item}) => (
                        <ListItem
                          ...
                          ...
                          onPress={() =>{this.Hide_Soft_Keyboard(); this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2')}}                                                      
                        /> ) }
                        />
                  </List>
```