# Prevent keyboard dismiss. React native

Tags: react-native

How to keep keyboard opened when i have `TextInput` and `Touchable` near input that sends message. So i want to send message without double tap on touchable. First to hide keyboard, second to send message. How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native have to double click for onPress to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808294/react-native-have-to-double-click-for-onpress-to-work)

Answer (score 29):

Use `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` to handle this.

Example:-

```
<ScrollView
        keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'} >
</ScrollView>
```

Deprecated Properties:-

`false`, deprecated, use `'never'` instead

`true`, deprecated, use `'always'` instead

[source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps)

Comment: Don't use `true`, use 'always', as true is deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps).

The following keeps the keyboard open when content is tapped but closes the keyboard when dragged.

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" keyboardDismissMode="on-drag">

  {/* Content containing interactive elements such as <Touchable /> */}

</ScrollView>
```

**Note**
Any parent ScrollViews/VirtualizedLists/Flatlists/SectionLists will also need to set `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"`

[Here are some gory details if you're interested](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4229).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) property of ScrollView. Setting it to "handled" should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Why scrollview? I need `TouchableHighlight`

Comment: if you wrap your screen in ScrollView, you can set the keyboard behaviour.

Comment: You can add `scrollEnabled={false}` to disable scrolling if you don't need it.

Comment: That's not working. Tried 'always', 'handled' but no one worked for me. Keyboard closes after tapping item in scrollview

Answer (score 0):

just only wrap you submit button with scrollview and then make sure u need to add two props  keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always" and keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
like this ...

```
<TextInput/> 
<ScrollView
            contentContainerStyle={{
              width: SIZES.width / 6,
              height: 60,
            }}
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
            keyboardDismissMode="on-drag">
<TouchableOpacity onPress={}>
</TouchableOpacity>
</ScrollView>
```