# How to prevent keyboard dismiss while touching outside in react native KeyboardAvoidingView

Tags: react-native

Actually i am working on chat window. Chat window will have different type of display types like text, selection box, dropdown, etc.So now i have taken keyboardavoidingview as root view and inside this i have used flatlist to render different types.But if i click on any item keyboard is closing in ios simulator. How to handle this one.

code:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} forceInset={{top: 'never'}}>

    <HeaderComponent></HeaderComponent>

    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior= {(Platform.OS === 'ios')? "padding" : null}
                          behavior="height"
                          style={{flex: 1}}>

        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#F2F2F2'}}>
            <FlatList
                ref='lst'
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />


        </View>
</KeyboardAvoidingView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: I think you can try this package instead : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you need

[keyboardShouldPersistTaps](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps) and [keyboardDismissMode](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboarddismissmode)

```
    <FlatList
      ref='lst'
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
      keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
     />
```

Note that Flatlist inherits the scrollview props. That's why this props will work on a flat list too.

EDIT :

Sorry Possible duplicate of this
[Prevent keyboard dismiss. React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883463/prevent-keyboard-dismiss-react-native)

Comment: i didn't check that flatlist keyboardShouldPersistTaps property

Comment: its okay there's a small font text there that says it inherits scrollview. It's easy to miss. I'm a victim of that too in the past lol